# JFET self bias-configuration quiescent point calculation

Tags: bias, jfet

I am learning JFET biasing configurations. For self biasing configuration (circuit below), the quiescent point is determined as the intersection of the following equations<sup>(1)</sup> -

```
Vgs = -Id * Rs
Id = Idss * (1 - Vgs/Vp)^2
```

[image: JFET self bias]

The mathematical solution substitutes `Vgs` in the second equation and solves for `Id` from the quadratic equation.

This seems wrong to me. The value of `Id` should also depend on the values of `Rd` and `Rs`. Even if I assume `Rd = 0` (seems to be the case for any application schematics I see), I think the impedance provided by `Rs` is not accounted for in the equation solution.

The way I see it, `Idss` practically is not a constant value and it changes (very slightly) with `Vds`. Datasheets also rate `Idss` at a particular `Vds`. For the given circuit `Vds = Vdd - Id*Rd - Id*Rs`. Assuming -

```
Idss = f(Vds) // Not sure how it's related (looks linear from a graph though)
=> Idss = f(Vdd - Id*Rd - Id*Rs)
```

So the solution for `Id` should actually involve something like -

```
Id = f(Vdd - Id*Rd - Id*Rs) * (1 - (-Id * Rs)/Vp)^2
```

Even if we assume `Rd = 0`, for large enough values of `Rs` the difference in the solutions of these two equations should be non-trivial.

So my question is -

1. **Is my assumption correct? Does value of `Rs` determine `Id` other than just what is affected by `Vgs` value?**
2. **What is the relationship between `Vds` and `Idss` in the saturation region?**

(1) - See Boylestad Nashelky section 6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to validate the assumption that `Rs` determines `Id`, let's plot `Vgs` vs `Ids` for different values of `Rs`. The results plotted are based on the following ngspice simulation -

[image]

Plotting `Vgs` vs `Ids` we see that `Rs` affects `Vgs` more than `Id`. The variation in `Id` comes more from `Vds` rather than `Rs`. The curve going through the points is Shockley's equation with `Vp = -2.25 V` (taken from SPICE simulation model) and `Idss = 0.006765 A` (calculated graphically when `Vds = 15V`). Note that the range of `Rs` values is reasonable enough for Q-point determination.

[image]

Also, here is a graph to show how much `Rs` affects `Vds`. We see that it's minimal for the chosen range. So effect on `Id` or `Idss` is also minimal.

[image]

**So, does value of Rs determine Id other than just what is affected by Vgs value?** - Yes it does. However for calculating the quiescent point it does not matter much (as we can see from the two graphs). Even changes in `Vds` does not affect it much since the slope of the changes is close the slope of the Q-point and origin. So, solution of Shockley's equation and the linear relation of `Vgs` and `Rs` is a fairly good approximation.

**What is the relationship between Vds and Idss in the saturation region?** - I found this to have a rather complex answer (and too elaborate to be posted here). I would recommend reading "Microelectronic devices and circuits - Clifton G. Fonstad" for advanced JFET models.

Comment: For JFET the maximum drain current you can get is Idss when RS = 0 (and Vgs = 0V). If you want to have a smaller drain current to flow you need to add Rs resistor to reduce the Id to a value lower than Idss (negative Vgs --- > Vgs < 0).  As for the saturation region. When the JFET is in saturation region the Vds voltage has no influence on the drain current. In this region, JFET behaves just like a constant current source. In this region only Vgs voltage "controls" the drain current.

Answer (score 1):

In this regime, the FET is totally saturated and especially JFET in saturation have a very small dependence of \$I_\text D\$ on \$V_\text{DS}\$. That is, why these equations are independent of \$V_\text{DS}\$.

[image: Image from]

Image from [here](https://learnabout-electronics.org/Semiconductors/fet_02a.php)

But you can think of extreme cases, where this picture breaks down:

- very large \$R_\text S\$ will put the JFET into a regime where \$I_\text D\$ and \$V_\text{GS}\$ are no longer squarely related.
- very large \$R_\text D\$ will eventually leave too little \$V_\text{DS}\$ to keep the JFET channel saturated and current will drop. A usual value is that the JFET needs roughly \$V_\text{DS}\gtrapprox\$ 1..2 V to reach saturation, where \$I_\text D\$ will become independent of \$V_\text{DS}\$.
- The dependence of \$I_\text{DSS}\$ on \$V_\text{DS}\$ is no different. It is just the particular case where \$V_\text{GS}=\$ 0 V in the image above.

Comment: Based on simulations I found that Idss changes quite a bit based on Vds (more than 10%). However the changes in Vds and consequently Idss is minimal for reasonable value ranges of Rs. Also the Q-point is minimally affected much by changes in Vds also since the slope of the Vds changes and the line for self-biasing are similar. I posted an answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/663485/316273 based on my findings. Any feedback / criticism is appreciated.